# How to set image style for media browser in node edit form?

Tags: media

I am using the media browser that is part of the [media module](https://drupal.org/project/media) to upload or select images on a node edit form.
I an image is already uploaded it is shown in the edit form in it's original size. If the image is large this makes the whole edit form unusable. Where can I set the images style, that is used for the edit form?

Answer (score 2):

Once you have chosen the image and clicked save and the overlay is closed, images are display in the "Media thumbnail" image style. Did you perhaps change the settings for that image style under admin/config/media/image-styles?

Comment: I don't have this style, but I never edited or deleted it. Can I recreate it?

Comment: Hover the available image styles on admin/config/media/image-styles and check the urls for the machine name "media_thumbnail". I my case the image style label had changed but the machine name was still the same. In some cases you can click Revert to restore the image style as defined by the media library