# How to change the image style for image preview in node-add/edit form?

Tags: media

IN a related question, "[How to set image style for media browser in node edit form?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/115830/how-to-set-image-style-for-media-browser-in-node-edit-form/115832#115832)" one response noted that "Once you have chosen the image and clicked save and the overlay is closed, images are display in the "Media thumbnail" image style."

How can I change this automatic behavior such that the preview image is displayed in my custom image style?

Answer (score 0):

**If you are** using the [Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) module, I couldn't find a way to change it so it doesn't use the "Media thumbnail" image style. But what you could do is edit the "Media thumbnail" image style by going to `/admin/config/media/image-styles/edit/media_thumbnail` and clicking on the <kbd>override</kbd> button which will let you edit it to your liking. (Tested on Drupal 7)

---

If **you're not** using the [Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) module, you can by going to your content type's Manage Fields and clicking on edit for your image field. Scroll down a bit until you see **Preview image style**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @sssweat. I would like to change the thumbnail for one content type. If I override the default Media thumbnail, the preview image style will change in all content types.